# At what point in a US airport have I been "admitted" to the US for legal purposes?

Tags: human-rights, immigration, travel, borders, bill-of-rights

I understand that prior to crossing being admitted to the US the rights I take for granted on US soil [do not apply to me](http://www.americanbar.org/publications/gp_solo/2013/may_june/what_are_your_rights_screenings_and_checkpoints.html). But it isn't clear to me when passing through a US airport *where* "admission" has occured. Unlike, for example, the UK, where clear signage unambiguously marks an actual border, US airports have a confusing series of stages to pass through.

At what point in passing through these stages have I technically been admitted to the US, and acquired the full legal protections I expect there?

Comment: @K-C: Sorry, I had the wrong link in the question. Those specifically mentioned as not being fully in force in the (corrected) link.

Comment: Asked and answered on Travel.SE, including legal citations: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/88425/1362

Comment: @NateEldredge: No, crossposted here because the answers there were so bad (and it's getting deleted anyway),

Comment: Ok but at the very least you should include a link.  I don't see any reason to think it's going to be deleted.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that your phrase "the full legal protections I expect there" is vague.  We don't know what protections you are expecting to have.  It might be that you acquire different protections at different points in the process.  And it might be that there are some protections which you are mistaken in expecting to ever acquire.  Can you be more specific as to what "protections" you mean?

Comment: Can you also explain what was so bad about the answer by Sheik Paul which I linked?  It seemed to clearly address the "technically admitted" issue (except, as I mentioned in comments there, that it could explain the distinction between immigration and customs).

Comment: @NateEldredge: Well, for one thing, it's [clearly wrong](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/88432/1607) (and takes quite a few words in being wrong).

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is exactly correct on the issue of "admitted".  The answer by chx is a hyperbolic quibble over the meaning of "full legal protections" which as I said is vague and should be clarified.  The existence of internal checkpoints does not mean you "kiss your legal protections goodbye", whatever that even means.  It's a place where your "admitted" status might be subject to verification.

Comment: @NateEldredge: It's probably best to make these remarks (and perhaps edit the answers) [over at Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/88425/1362). Then I can perhaps close this one (of that one stays open).

Comment: WRT rights, physical presence within the borders suffices – you are then in US jurisdiction, not Canadian, Mexican or Irish. The act of admission does not legally change anything, except your ability to move about freely in the US. When you have passed inspection, you are free to go. There is a concern over acts committed "after admission" which can lead to removal, having to do with the entry / admission distinction. That does not seem to be your concern, so it seems that physical presence is what counts.

Comment: @user6726 but people in immigration detention seem to have limited access to legal counsel; does that not change after being admitted?